# Why GNU Make's secondary expansion does not work with pattern rules for dependencies?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider this makefile:

```
%: %.c
    @echo making $@
    @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pid: $$(basename $$@)
    $(<D)/$(<F) --pidfile=$<.pid
```

Here, the first rule builds a program and second rule starts it, producing a pid-file. *Note: I know that secondary expansion is unnecessary in this example; the real makefile is more complex and I really need secondary expansion there.*

So, typing `make foo.pid`, I expect Make to build `foo` from `foo.c` by the first rule and then run `./foo --pidfile=foo.pid` by the second one.

However, it does not seem to work:

```
$ make -f Makefile.test foo.pid
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.pid'.  Stop.
```

This somehow relates to secondary-expanded dependencies which are provided by pattern rules. If I write either

- `%.pid: %` in the second rule (i. e. get rid of secondary-expansion), or
- `foo: %: %.c` in the first rule (i. e. write an explicit static pattern rule),

it all suddenly works. Why? Is this a limitation of GNU Make? In my case, I'd like to avoid pre-listing all possible programs in the first rule.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but it works if you add a dummy prefix to the intermediate file, so instead of `foo.c=>foo=>foo.pid` you use `foo.c=>foo.b=>foo.pid`. (I'm using GNU Make 3.81)

Comment: For %.pid: $$(basename $$@), $@ is only meaningful inside the rule, instead of in the prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

I think your situation is described in section 10.5.5 Match-Anything Pattern Rules. Whay you have here is a non-terminal match-anything rule, which is not allowed to match  a file name that indicates a specific type of data.

If you had let's say

```
%:: %.c
    @echo making $@
    @touch $@
```

it would work.

Comment: ...except that it doesn't. Which makes sense, because I want the match-anything rule to match `foo`, which is not a "specific type of data" — in other words, there are no non-match-anything implicit rules which apply to this target.